# Remove hyperlink in PDFTron Objective C

Tags: swift, objective-c, pdf, pdftron

[image]

How to remove entire hyperlink in pdf file.If anybody knows please answer this question.

Library used in PDFTron and ObjectiveC language.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cpdf -remove-annotations in.pdf -o out.pdf`. This does remove all annotations, but if you only have link annotations, that would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

For [link annotations](https://docs.apryse.com/api/ios/Classes/PTLink.html) in the document, you can edit and delete them with the link creation tool ([`PTLinkCreate`](https://docs.apryse.com/api/ios/Classes/PTLinkCreate.html) class). While the link-create tool is active, existing link annotations will be selected when you tapped. From the annotation-selection popup menu you can tap "Delete" (the last menu option - you may need to scroll or tap the arrow in the menu to see it) to delete the link annotation.